# Saving Images to a docx file using AS3 or JavaScript for a flex standalone web based app. (No back end server)

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3, apache-flex, docx

I have a standalone web based app in Flex. It allows you to take screen shots of  certain graphs and charts. Now I require to store these multiple screen shots in a docx file which the user can save locally. Is there a way I can do this in a web based Flex App? If not is there a way to do it in JavaScript if I pass the data to JavaScript using ExternalInterface?
Note: 1) Can not switch to AIR app.
      2) Cannot use any server side code.

Comment: exposing file API from any web based app is a great security threat. Hence I guess without the help of any server side code. It will be really difficult if not impossible.

Comment: The way it would work that you build the .docx at runtime (.docx is a .zip with the contents as XML-text and WMF-image files (and others) so it would be string manipulation mostly), zipping it with something like AS3 Commons Zip and sending data for saving in JavaScript if you can't switch to an AIR app. So yeah, really difficult, maybe not impossible. Saving the images as .PDF-file would/could be much easier.

Comment: As @PeteTNT suggested I used the AS3 Commons Zip to load a .docx file(using it as a template) and manipulating it to add my images and finally save the file. Now I am able to open the file in MS Word Viewer. But the issue now is that that it does not open in Open Office Writer. Although the original template file can be opened and viewed in the Open Office Writer.

Answer (score 0):

DocxGenJS might be good for you (I'm the creator of DocxGen)

[Demo](http://javascript-ninja.fr/docxgenjs/examples/demo.html)

[Demo: Image Replacing](http://javascript-ninja.fr/docxgenjs/examples/imageTagging.html)

[GitHubRepo](https://github.com/edi9999/docxgenjs)

It works only on FF3+ and Chrome, not IE.
You could port it to Flex to make a IE compatible version (IE doesn't work because the reading of documents in Ajax with DataBytes isn't well supported)